# Jquery - First instance where condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a custom calendar. 
I'm working on the position of the calendar days.
I'm working on a function that needs to find the first time a condition is true.

Looking at my code below, I need to `console.log("test")` only the first time **var J** has a greater value than **var currentDate**.

Here is my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/c33Xj/

```
$("#Cal tbody tr:first-child td").each(function(){
     var currentDate = (new Date).getDate();
     var h = $(this).text();
     if (h == weekDays[currentDay]) {
         var j = $(this).index();
         console.log(j);
     }
});
```

Comment: And what is `j` ? I mean what `$(this).index()` exactly is? Day of month? 0 = first day? Or 1 = first day? or what?

Comment: My calendar is a single row. J is each time the week day(eg. Mon) appears.

Comment: So by finding the first time J is greater than current date, I know what calendar day to mark as today. I can't have Jul. 23rd, fall on the first monday of my calendar.

Comment: You need to give us a html or at least function creating calendar table.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c33Xj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return false;
```

will cancel the rest of the iterations.

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ (last paragraph right above Examples section.)

Comment: wow....sometimes excess knowledge fails to find simplest solutions...perfect : +1!!

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
var e = $("#Cal tbody tr:first-child td").filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() === weekDays[currentDay] 
}).first()
```

Then do whatever you want with `e` variable.

Answer (score -1):

Use a global (common) flag to all the elements and change its state the first time you call Console.log, so following times check this condition:

```
var logged = false;
$("#Cal tbody tr:first-child td").each(function(){
     var currentDate = (new Date).getDate();
     var h = $(this).text();
     if (h == weekDays[currentDay]) {
     var j = $(this).index();
     if(loged==false)
     {
          console.log(j);
          logged = true;
    }
 }
});

logged = false; //Restart for the next time;
```

Answer (score -2):

For identifying which day is the current day, I would use the modulus operator (%). While a division (30 / 30) leads to the result (zero), modulus means the rest. So 30 % 30 is 0, 30 % 20 is 10 (20 fits 30 one time with 10 rest) etc.

j % currentDate is zero if j is today:

```
if(j % currentDate == 0) {
    console.log("test");
}
```

Comment: bad idea... how about 28/31 days months?